# Save result of multiplication to existing array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiplication

Consider the following code:

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4])
b = numpy.array([5,6,7,8])
# here a new array (b*2) will be created and name 'a' will be assigned to it
a = b * 2
```

So, can numpy write the result of `b*2` directly to memory already allocated for `a`, without allocating a new array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible - you need to use [`np.multiply`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html#numpy.multiply) with its [`out`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments) parameter:

```
np.multiply(b, 2, out=a)
```

The array `a` is now filled with the result of `b * 2` (and no new memory was allocated to hold the output of the function).

All of NumPy's ufuncs have the `out` parameter which is especially handy when working with large arrays; it helps to keep memory consumption to a minimum by allowing arrays to be reused. The only caveat is that the array has to the correct size/shape to hold the output of the function.

Comment: But if there is a more complex expression, e. g. `b*2+c`, can I evaluate it without introducing arrays for temporal results: `multiply(b,2,temp)` and `add(temp,c,a)`?

Comment: @Leonidas: unfortunately this is one of the limitations of NumPy, the operations have to split out as you've written in your comment. You might be interested in the [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) library which goes some way to fixing this problem.

Comment: Thank you. And here is the answer to my question: [universal functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html)